# Quick way to change the interpreter

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have often to run tests in multiple environments and compare the results. Is there a way in pydev to switch the interpreter for the next debug session without having to go in:

- Preferences
- PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar
- Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change the interpreter in the launch configuration instead of globally.

1. *Run* menu
2. *Run Configurations...*
3. Select the configuration you are using.
4. In *Interpreter* tab choose which interpreter you want to use. (See 6-pointed star in screenshot below.)

At this point you probably have not saved any clicks. What you can do now is *Duplicate* the launch configuration and have different launch configurations for different interpreters. This will allow you to run with no changes different python interpreters (by choosing the different launch configurations from the Run menu/toolbar item). I have highlighted with a 4-pointed star the duplicate button.

[image]